# golang api when to use the cancel method on context

Tags: go

I have a standard golang api which takes the following flow

```
handler.go->service.go->repository.go->elasticRepository.
```

In all these cases from the handler I am passing down the `context` object all the way down to the `repository.go` file.  My question is around the use of the `cancel` method on the `context` object.  Mid-way if the user cancels the request I am listning to the done signal on the context object on the `handler.go` but once I get the signal what should I do next ? should I call cancel?.  My `service.go` and `repository.go` files don't do much other than just passing down the paramters for the moment, however the `repository.go` file has a reference to the elastic client which is also using this same `context` object.  My assumption is that if the user cancels the request, the elastic client will automatically get this notification and cancel and I don't have to do anything, is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the code of ElasticSearch golang client, and found out:

Every ES request uses the transport client:

> [go-elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/184c47e37ebc5dfb5e36ebca6ba6dd8b625cdbb8/elasticsearch.go#L185) <- [elastictransport](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-transport-go/blob/bbee439d559c711c212596e8d6aec2167c5f5395/elastictransport/elastictransport.go#L144) <- [net/http.DefaultTransport](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d15481b8c7f5f73a8b987a0c1deea04659ed0bb0/src/net/http/transport.go#L43)

So the call process would be:

> Your program -> go-elasticsearch API -> [transport.Perform()](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/esapi/api.cat.aliases.go#L166) -> elastictransport.Perform() -> [net/http.Transport.RoundTrip()](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-transport-go/blob/HEAD/elastictransport/elastictransport.go#L342)

Let's look at the code snippet of net/http.Transport.roundTrip [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d15481b8c7f5f73a8b987a0c1deea04659ed0bb0/src/net/http/transport.go#L562):

```
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        req.closeBody()
        return nil, ctx.Err()
    default:
    }
```

the **ctx** is passed all the way to this function!

Back to your question:

> if the user cancels the request, the elastic client will automatically get this notification and cancel and I don't have to do anything, is this correct ?

The answer is:

> Yes, the ES client will return, right after the context is canceled

Comment: thanks, so I don't need to listen for the `done` signal either in the `handler`, `service`, or `repository` layer ? I tried listning to the done signal in each of the layers, but not sure what I should do when I get the signal other than just returning ?

Comment: you don't need to listen to the "Done" channel,  if you have some resource to release, you can handle the error: "if err == context.Canceled { do recycle stuff }", otherwise, just return is enough